# provide model and its relationship models to javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to provide a model Performances and the link models attached to it (Performer models) to javascript as json.

I know i can provide Performance models using the following code

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
    window.performances = <%=raw Performance.order('date DESC').limit(99).to_json %>;
<% end %>
```

Now for every Performance I would like to attach Performers that are linked to it in the same json file.

How could i accomplish this ?

To clarify there is a Performance has_many Performers relationships. So in ruby file i can just access it with Performance.performers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not figured out how to get the performers by themselves but I have used includes method on Performance to get both Performances and Performers in one table:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
window.performances = <%=raw Performance.includes(:performers).order('date DESC').to_json(:include => {:performers =>  {
                                                                                    :except => [ :created_at, :updated_at ]
                                                                                    }}, :except => [ :created_at, :updated_at ]) %> ;
<% end %>
```

From there I can easily get performers in my JavaScript  by using json manipulation.

```
#you can use a loop to loop through each performance
currentPerformance = window.performances[fileIndex];
performers += "_" + currentPerformance.performers[0].name; 
#this will return the first performer name from performances at fileIndex
```

If anybody knows a better way to just get the performers without the performances please post below and ill accept it as best answer